# cannot find -lz library in lxml2

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am trying to compile a code using the quickfix library using:

```
g++ -o main tradeclient.cpp Application.cpp -std=c++11 -fexceptions -finline-functions -lquickfix -lpthread -lxml2 -lz
```

According to the documentation, I need to include -lxml2 and -lz... However, lz is not found, although I have installed the lxml2 library already. This is what I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where can I find that library...?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/), a compression library. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```